# Tensorflow/Keras stops using gpu after recompiling model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to train my sequential model (RNN->GRU->Dense) with Keras/TensorFlow 2.0 in two phases with different loss weights in the two phases. To change the loss weights, I need to recompile the model between the two phases. My problem is that training becomes much much slower after the recompilation, and I can see no other explanation than that the GPU is no longer used. Here is the relevant code:

```
# Build model
input_ = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, num_features))
masking = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.)(input_)
rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(24, return_sequences=True, name="rnn")(masking)
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(16, return_sequences=True, name="gru")(rnn)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="dense1")(gru)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.math.sigmoid, name="dense2")(gru)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[dense1, dense2])

# Learn reate scheduler: Reduce learn reate by factor 0.5 when no progress after 7 epochs
reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, patience=7, min_lr=0.0001)

# Compile and fit, phase 1
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'], sample_weight_mode="temporal", loss_weights=[0.7, 0.3], metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=BATCHES_PER_EPOCH, epochs=375, callbacks=[reduce_lr])

# Recompile and fit, phase 2
optimizer.lr = 0.001
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'], sample_weight_mode="temporal", loss_weights=[0.99, 0.01], metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=BATCHES_PER_EPOCH, epochs=125, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

Output at end of phase 1 and start of phase 2 shows how training becomes about 5 times slower:

```
Epoch 374/375
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.1177 - dense1_loss: 0.1479 - dense2_loss: 0.0473 - dense1_accuracy: 0.9249 - dense2_accuracy: 0.9784
Epoch 375/375
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.1177 - dense1_loss: 0.1479 - dense2_loss: 0.0473 - dense1_accuracy: 0.9249 - dense2_accuracy: 0.9784
Epoch 1/125
4/4 [==============================] - 27s 7s/step - loss: 0.1494 - dense1_loss: 0.1504 - dense2_loss: 0.0478 - dense1_accuracy: 0.9225 - dense2_accuracy: 0.9779
Epoch 2/125
4/4 [==============================] - 24s 6s/step - loss: 0.1603 - dense1_loss: 0.1614 - dense2_loss: 0.0545 - dense1_accuracy: 0.9201 - dense2_accuracy: 0.9750
```

What could be the explanation? Is the model reorganized in some way when it's recompiled, so TensorFlow can no longer map the operations to the GPU?

(I have tried just changing the loss weights with `model.loss_weights = [0.99, 0.01]` but that doesn't work - recompilation is necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Build two separate models with same layers (weights):

```
input_ = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, num_features))
masking = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.)(input_)
rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(24, return_sequences=True, name="rnn")(masking)
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(16, return_sequences=True, name="gru")(rnn)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax, name="dense1")(gru)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.math.sigmoid, name="dense2")(gru)

model1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[dense1, dense2])
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[dense1, dense2])
```

Compile and fit each one separately, with different optimiser instances:

```
optimizer1 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.1)
optimizer2 = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, clipvalue=0.1)

model1.compile(optimizer=optimizer1, loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'], sample_weight_mode="temporal", loss_weights=[0.7, 0.3], metrics=['accuracy'])
model2.compile(optimizer=optimizer2, loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'], sample_weight_mode="temporal", loss_weights=[0.99, 0.01], metrics=['accuracy'])

model1.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=BATCHES_PER_EPOCH, epochs=375, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
model2.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=BATCHES_PER_EPOCH, epochs=125, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I want. I really want one single model first trained with one set of loss weights, then continue with the same model from that point with another set of loss weights. You may wonder why - it's a long story, but in short it's an experiment where I want to see if forcing the training to recognize a secondary output in a first phase may lead it towards a better final solution, although the final solution actually only needs to recognize the primary output. This seems to be the case, but training the second phase is awfully slow for unknown reasons.

Comment: In the code, the weights between the models refer the same variables. The models are identical in that they basically refer to the same memory locations.

Comment: You can verify this too. Train model1, then use model1.evaluate() and model2.evaluate(). They'll give identical results over the same data.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for clarifying! Okay I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't help - fitting model2 is still much slower than model1. Even reusing the same optimizer for both doesn't help.